# SQL JOIN Variable

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

tasks

- id
- name
- description
- parent_id
- parent_type

accounts

- id
- name

leads

- id
- name

My query that works looks

```
SELECT tasks.name,date_due, tasks.description, accounts.name FROM tasks 
JOIN accounts
on tasks.parent_id = accounts.id
WHERE DATE(date_due) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND tasks.assigned_user_id=1
```

What I need is to make the `accounts` a variable - it can be either accounts or leads, depends on the `tasks.parent_type` value.

Any tips how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT tasks.name,date_due, tasks.description,
  CASE WHEN parent_Type = 1 then
    accounts.name
  WHEN parent_Type=2 then
    leads.name
  END as Name
FROM tasks
  LEFT JOIN accounts
    on tasks.parent_id = accounts.id
  LEFT JOIN leads
    on leads.id = tasks.parent_ID
WHERE DATE(date_due) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND tasks.assigned_user_id=1
```

Or if you know ID will not be in one of the two tables a coalease would work.  Coalease takes the first non-null value in a series.

```
SELECT tasks.name,date_due, tasks.description,
  coalesce(accounts.name, leads.name) as Name
FROM tasks
  LEFT JOIN accounts
    on tasks.parent_id = accounts.id
  LEFT JOIN leads
    on leads.id = tasks.parent_ID
WHERE DATE(date_due) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND tasks.assigned_user_id=1
```

Otherwise dynamic SQL has to be written to adjust a tablename on the fly: an example of which would be: 
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE concat("select * from ", @table_name, " where a=", @val);` as found http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2793.

However I'd caution you on this approach as it is subject to SQL injection opportunities without the proper controls in place for passed in variables.